# What kind of five-star cross or order is worn by the priest in this Paris Notre Dame mass?

Tags: cross, vestments, celebrations

In the following YouTube video clip ([Messe à Notre-Dame de Paris du 20 janvier 2019](https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=292&v=GC6zFJo5hxI&feature=youtu.be)) in which it is clearly visible that the priest celebrating mass in the Paris Notre Dame is wearing some kind of *Order* or special 5-star or cross medallion. What is this cross or star? What does it mean?

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that it is of a local or diocesan award or honour or something along those lines. It is not a medallion that I am familiar with. Perhaps, the Archdiocese of Paris confers this on the rectors of their cathedrals? Who knows? Perhaps it is a pilgrim medallion after a pilgrimage to Bethlehem?

Comment: I believe priests in the Roman Rite may not wear a pectoral crosses as they are reserved for bishops. Thus I am inclined to think that this is a diocesan medallion given to the rector of the cathedral who is also a monsignor. The Eastern Rite Churches employ the term [***Archpriest***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archpriest): According to the specific historical tradition, many churches throughout the world, other than basilicas, are under the authority of a priest who bears the title of archpriest. However, the title is mostly honorary ...